# Subtracting values from specific rows based on groupings in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101,101,101,101,101,101,
              102,102,102),
  Event = c('Negative_other_6',
            'Negative_other_6',
            'Negative_self_1',
            'Negative_other_6',
            'Negative_self_1',
            'Negative_self_1',
            'Negative_other_5',
            'Negative_other_5',
            'Negative_other_5'
            ),
  TrialType = c("ReframeNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeu",
                "ImmerseNeg", "ReframeNeg", "ImmerseNeg",
                "ReframeNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeg"),
  Rating = c(3,1,1,4,3,5,3,1,5)
)
```

For each of the same event, I want to subtract the rating `ReframeNeg` from `ImmerseNeg`. The output should be a new dataframe that's organized by `Subject` and `Event`. This should be the example output:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101,101, 102),
  Event = c('Negative_other_6',
            'Negative_self_1',
            'Negative_other_5'),
  NegAffDiff = c(1, 2, 2)
)
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option using your sample data. You can use pivot wider to create a column for each TrialType which assigns the Rating for each combo of Subject/Event/TrialType. Then find the difference between ReframeNeg and ImmerseNeg.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("TrialType"), values_from = "Rating") %>%
  mutate(NegAffDiff = ImmerseNeg - ReframeNeg) %>%
  select(Subject, Event, NegAffDiff)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Subject Event            NegAffDiff
    <dbl> <fct>                 <dbl>
1     101 Negative_other_6          1
2     101 Negative_self_1           2
3     102 Negative_other_5          2
```